# List Origami ~ Generation of new list from two

Tags: elixir

I am currently learning Elixir and I'm still trying to get my head around list comprehensions. I have two lists, content, and a throwaway list of prime numbers. I use two list comprehensions and then an `if` to decide that if it is a prime, to throw it away and delete it from the list.

```
iex(25)> content = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
iex(26)> for c <- content do                      
...(26)>   for s <- [1, 3, 5, 7] do
...(26)> 
...(26)>     if s == c do
...(26)>       List.delete(content, s)
...(26)>     end
...(26)> 
...(26)>   end
...(26)> end
[[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil],
 [nil, [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil],
 [nil, nil, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil],
 [nil, nil, nil, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]], [nil, nil, nil, nil],
 [nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

However, this is returning a strange result - lists of lists. I would have been expecting the code to return (which is what I want):

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Further, I also tried using this with `Enum.map` but made a bigger mess of it. Can someone please advise on how to get my desired 1xN list?

Comment: BTW, it doesn't work any better but you can combine your two list comprehensions into one construct: _for c <- content, s <- [1,3,5,7], do: if s==c, do: List.delete(content, s)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple way to do this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
o = [1,3,5,7,9]

d = l -- o
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to use a list comprehension to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

---

EDIT: I should have read the question a bit closer.  I thought the questioner was asking for a way to do this solely via a list comprehension.  Re-reading the question I can see that I just read it wrong. I've edited my answer.

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks for your insight! Also thanks to @whatyouhide

Answer (score 4):

A list comprehension with `for` always returns a list. So if you nest a `for` inside another `for`, the inner `for` will return a list so each element of the outer for will be a list - hence a list of lists. Nothing weird going on here.

Another thing that's happening and you may not expect is the amount of `nil`s in the result: the last expression of the inner `for` is an `if` without an `else` branch. This means that if the condition is true-ish the body of the `if` will be returned, but if it's false-ish then `nil` will be returned.

Onorio's answer (using `--/2`) looks good to me. Another thing you can do (without list comprehensions) is filtering out non-prime numbers with `Enum.reject/2`:

```
Enum.reject(content, fn n -> n in [1, 3, 5, 7] end)
```

If you absolutely want to use `for`, you can use guards:

```
for n in contents, not n in [1, 3, 5, 7], do: n
```

Just for the sake of completeness, one last thing: when you do `List.delete(contents, ...)`, you're not modifying the original `contents` list.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why @plotplot is getting that odd looking list. I was also a bit puzzled by that as well.